# How to override E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Account controller magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, customer-account

> Actually i am trying to override
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Account
>   controller using custom module here i am trying to to override

```
$message = __(
                        'You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.'
                    );
```

> this message

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Customer\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\UserLockedException;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator
     */
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @var AccountRedirect
     */
    protected $accountRedirect;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private $cookieMetadataManager;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param CustomerUrl $customerHelperData
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        CustomerUrl $customerHelperData,
        Validator $formKeyValidator,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->customerUrl = $customerHelperData;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Get scope config
     *
     * @return ScopeConfigInterface
     * @deprecated 100.0.10
     */
    private function getScopeConfig()
    {
        if (!($this->scopeConfig instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface)) {
            return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class
            );
        } else {
            return $this->scopeConfig;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie manager
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private function getCookieManager()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataManager) {
            $this->cookieMetadataManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataManager;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie metadata factory
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private function getCookieMetadataFactory()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataFactory) {
            $this->cookieMetadataFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Login post action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->session->regenerateId();
                    if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                        $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                        $metadata->setPath('/');
                        $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
                    }
                    $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
                    if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
                        $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
                        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                        // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
                        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
                        return $resultRedirect;
                    }
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                    $message = __(
                        'This account is not confirmed. <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.',
                        $value
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (UserLockedException $e) {
                    $message = __(
                        'You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.'
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                    $message = __('You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.');
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // PA DSS violation: throwing or logging an exception here can disclose customer password
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        __('An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.')
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            }
        }

        return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue?

Comment: i am trying to override this message ''You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.''

Comment: @hiteshbalpande instead of overriding class, you should use translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this :

in your `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost" type="Company\Module\Controller\Account\LoginPost" />
</config>
```

and now you can customize the message :

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\UserLockedException;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost
{

 /**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
 */
protected $customerAccountManagement;

 /**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator
 */
protected $formKeyValidator;

 /**
 * @var AccountRedirect
 */
protected $accountRedirect;

 /**
 * @var Session
 */
protected $session;

 /**
 * @var ScopeConfigInterface
 */
private $scopeConfig;

 /**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
 */
private $cookieMetadataFactory;

 /**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
 */
private $cookieMetadataManager;

 /**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Session $customerSession
 * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
 * @param CustomerUrl $customerHelperData
 * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
 * @param AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $customerSession,
    AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
    CustomerUrl $customerHelperData,
    Validator $formKeyValidator,
    AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
) {
    $this->session = $customerSession;
    $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
    $this->customerUrl = $customerHelperData;
    $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
    $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
    parent::__construct($context);
}



     /**
     * Get scope config
     *
     * @return ScopeConfigInterface
     * @deprecated 100.0.10
     */
    private function getScopeConfig()
    {
        if (!($this->scopeConfig instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface)) {
            return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class
            );
        } else {
            return $this->scopeConfig;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie manager
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private function getCookieManager()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataManager) {
            $this->cookieMetadataManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataManager;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie metadata factory
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private function getCookieMetadataFactory()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataFactory) {
            $this->cookieMetadataFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Login post action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->session->regenerateId();
                    if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                        $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                        $metadata->setPath('/');
                        $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
                    }
                    $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
                    if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
                        $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
                        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                        // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
                        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
                        return $resultRedirect;
                    }
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                    $message = __(
                        'This account is not confirmed. <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.',
                        $value
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (UserLockedException $e) {
                    $message = __(
                        '<Your Custom Message>'
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                    $message = __('<Your Custom Message>');
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // PA DSS violation: throwing or logging an exception here can disclose customer password
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        __('An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.')
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            }
        }

        return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot declare class Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost, because the name is already in use in E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Controller\Account\LoginPost.php on line 205 error is showing

Comment: I see so you already custom extension that override LoginPost.php Class, just remove my answer question, and go to `app/code/Inkind/NavData/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php` just change error message that you want.

Comment: ok i understand

Answer (score 4):

To change only error message you should use translations instead of file overriding.

You can add translations by creating csv file at following location

`app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv`

and change the message as you want.

`"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.","Your custom message."`